# Hosting WCF SOAP, and WCF REST service as Azure App Services

Tags: c#, rest, azure, wcf, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host existing WCF service and a WCF REST service as a Azure App Services. I have used the Publish option from Visual studio like in the post [Here](https://aspdotnetcodehelp.wordpress.com/2017/11/13/hosting-wcf-in-azure-app-service/)

I am able to browse to the hosted URL for the WCF SOAP site and the WCF REST site, but when i add a service reference for the WCF SOAP site and call a method on it i get below error

Same with the WCF rest service when i call a REST method, i get 404 now found error.

**There was no endpoint listening at https://wcfservice.azurewebsites.net/WebService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**

From the failed request log i.e w3svcxxxx log, it says the request **https://WcfService:80/Webservice.svc 404 not found status.**

For the WCF Rest Service
**https://WcfService:80/RESTservice.svc/GetData 404 not found status.**

Why is the service internally calling a https://WcfService:80, would this require an configuration to setup. Tried to search around to see if i could find any help around this but could not find much.

Also, i have another WCF site that i had deployed to the App Services, which is setup with a basicHttpBinding and this site worked fine and i was able to get data using it.

Below is the web.config setting on the web site, i am using wsHttpBinging for the WCF SOAP service

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebServiceOnline">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="WcfService.WebServiceOnline" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceOnline">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="wsSecurityByTransport" contract="WcfService.IWebServiceForOnline" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="WcfService.RESTService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceOnline">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IRESTService" name="RunningBarbus.Services.RunningBarbusService" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="locahost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsSecurityByTransport">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<services>   <service name="WcfService.WebServiceOnline" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceOnline">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="wsSecurityByTransport" contract="WcfService.IWebServiceForOnline" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />   </service>   <service name="WcfService.RESTService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceOnline">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IRESTService" name="RunningBarbus.Services.RunningBarbusService" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="locahost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />   </service> </services>
```

There may be an issue in the configuration file.  We could expose the additional service endpoint for wshttpbinding.
Here is my configuration, and it works properly over Azure.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <!--http, https are all configurated-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev" bindingConfiguration="com"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="myservice" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="com">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Result**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank for the response, still having problem with a WCF REST service hosting on Azure, added the webHttpBinding as bindingcontract as given example above, i get an error. "Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]. "

Comment: We are supposed to add ssl binding(enable https)for the service plan in Azure app service.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am able to connect my site as REST and get data, though i get 400 Bad Request as a response, but i also get the desired JSON response form the method, i can now check further on the reason for 400 error code i get.

Comment: How can i get the response as JSON using wshttpbinding?