# Migrating WCF service with wsHttpBinding to Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, wcf, azure-appservice

How can i migrate a legacy WCF service on .Net Framework 4.5 with wsHttpBinding to Azure App Service. As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/migration/app-service
wsHttpBinding is not supported in Azure App Service

Answer (score 0):

WSHttpBinding Class applies to .NET Framework4.5.

[image]

Please refer this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Azure, we cannot use Windows Authentication (the default configuration of WSHttpBinding) unless we use WAAD and have the cloud server join the local domain. 
Therefore, you need to turn off authentication, or use another authentication mechanism (such as username and password)
For specific steps, you can see the tutorial below.
[WCF Security and Authentication in Azure (WsHttpBinding with username and psw credentials)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092557/WCF-Security-and-Authentication-in-Azure-WsHttpBin)
[Hosting WCF SOAP, and WCF REST service as Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337794/hosting-wcf-soap-and-wcf-rest-service-as-azure-app-services) 
[How to: Migrate and publish a web application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service?view=vs-2022)